# Right circular shift using arraycopy method java

Tags: java, arrays

I need help on how to use the arraycopy method in Java.

I have an array of characters such as:

[a, b, c, d]

and I want to perform a circular shift to right, for example, if the circular shifts is of integer 2, then the characters will shift two places to right, resulting in:

[c, d, a, b]

I want to know how I can implement this using the arraycopy method.

I have managed to implement it for when it comes to shifting the array to the left for a certain number of shifts, as follows:

```
System.arraycopy(sArray, leftShifts, leftShiftedArray, 0, n - leftShifts);
System.arraycopy(sArray, 0, leftShiftedArray, n - leftShifts, leftShifts);
```

I'm just finding it  difficult to do the same for the right.

Thank you

Comment: We'll, there's two ways to go. You can make a new method, or you can observe that a right shift is equivalent to a left shift at a different offset. ie) for a length of `n`, a left shift of `2` is a right of `n - 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating an `N`-element array left by `k` elements is equivalent to rotating the same array right by `N-k` elements. Therefore, all you need to do is substituting `leftShifts` with `n - rightShifts` in your formulas:

```
System.arraycopy(sArray, n - rightShifts, rightShiftedArray, 0, rightShifts);
System.arraycopy(sArray, 0, rightShiftedArray, rightShifts, n - rightShifts);
```

Comment: Don't forget to take the modulo of the `rightShifts` input. If its larger than `n` this will fail.